# simple arduino code exhibiting unexpected results

Tags: arduino

can anyone see why this simpple arduino code isnt working?

```
void loop() {
  if (Serial.available() > 0) {
    char num = Serial.read();  // Read a single character from serial input
    if (num == '5') {
      Serial.println("hooray!");
    }
    else {
      Serial.println("booo");
    } 
  }
}
```

it correctly prints hooray when i enter a 5 but also a boo and when i enter a non 5 char it prints boo twice. Thanks

I expected it to print hooray once if i entered a 5 and boo if i entered anything else.

Answer (score 0):

It was the line ending/ carriage return. i turned the line ending off my monitor and its working!